# Oracle - Filter results between modified working week

Tags: oracle, date, between, to-char, sysdate

Using Oracle, I am currently filtering data using AND schedstart BETWEEN (TRUNC(SYSDATE - (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'D')+6))) AND (TRUNC(SYSDATE - (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'D')-1)))) which isn't what I want.

My working week starts on a Wednesday and finishes on a Tuesday so I want my results to be filtered on my current working week. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Applying To_Char() to sysdate converts it to a character string. Probably what you intend is to remove the time component - do that with Trunc(sysdate)

Answer (score 0):

To find the beginning of the next week you would use Next_Day():

```
Next_Day(Trunc(SysDate),'WED')
```

Therefore to find the beginning of "this" week, use:

```
Next_Day(Trunc(SysDate),'WED') - 7
```

So to limit schedstart to the current working week (assuming schedstart has no time component):

```
schedstart between Next_Day(Trunc(SysDate),'WED') - 7
               and Next_Day(Trunc(SysDate),'WED') - 1
```

Comment: many thanks Mark, works great. How would I change to filter for the week ahead?

Comment: Add seven days to the sysdate.